# Expand rows based on arbitrary N and M

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have a parameter `V` which is equal to `100` on row `v`. I have another parameter `D` on row `d` that is equal to `100` too. I would like to create a dataframe with `N` rows above row `v` and `M` rows below row `d`, so that `v-N`th row is equal to `V + Nf` and `d+M`th row is equal to `D - Mf`. For this example, let's assume that `f` is equal to `5`:

Input:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(rw = structure(2:1, .Label = c("d", "v"), class = "factor"), 
    vals = c(100, 100)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Expected output:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(rw = structure(c(8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L
), .Label = c("d", "d+1", "d+2", "d+M", "v", "v-1", "v-2", "v-N"
), class = "factor"), vals = c(85, 90, 95, 100, 100, 105, 110, 
115)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

How can I achieve this? Let me know if you have any questions.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map` with `seq` to create a sequence of values by looping over the rows of 'vals' column, then pass another variable `byval` with sign for getting the sequence backwards or forwards for each corresponding element of 'vals' and pass it on the `by` argument in `seq` while setting the constant length of sequence to output as 4 ('n').  Then, set the names of the `list` wiith the 'rw'  column and convert the `list` to a two column data.frame with `stack`

```
byval <- 5
n <- 4
stack(setNames(Map(function(x, y) sort(seq(x, length.out = n, by = y)),
              df$vals, c(-byval, byval)), df$rw))[2:1]
```

---

If we need different `length.out`, pass it as another parameter

```
n1 <- 6
n2 <- 5
stack(setNames(Map(function(x, y, z) sort(seq(x, length.out = z, by = y)),
              df$vals, c(-byval, byval), c(n1, n2)), df$rw))[2:1]
```

Comment: Thanks, got the idea! I would appreciate if you could explain the logic. For example, what does `length.out` do here?

Comment: @AK88 I added some explanations.  Do you need the `+1`, `+2` etc. as well in the output

Comment: Yes, that would be very helpful to know what `N` is for the end user. Also, can we add unequal rows on the above and below? As in, can we have not only `n`, but a parameter `m` as well?

Comment: @AK88 For that you can describe `byval1 <- 5; `byval2 <- 10; tack(setNames(Map(function(x, y) sort(seq(x, length.out = n, by = y)),
              df$vals, c(-byval1, byval2)), df$rw))[2:1]`

Comment: I am sorry, I think this is not correct. Because the add-on is the same, but I want to expand rows upwards 5 times and downwards 4 times. So I would have `75` the first value and `120` the last value. I hope it is clear.

Comment: @AK88 Can you check the update.  it is the length.out that. you also needs to be passed into `Map` as separate entries

Comment: Awesome! Is `z` parameter automatically defined? Also, can we add `+1`, `+2`, `+N`, `-1`, `-2`, `-M` to the `ind` column?

Comment: @AK88  The `function(x, y, z)` is anonymous function depends on how many parameters. are. passed into `Map`.  IN the first example, there is only. two,  so `function(x, y)`.  If you want to pass more, it woulld be `function(x, y, z, u)` depends on the number of parameters, you can name it anything as it is a function created on the fly without any assignment